# How to include variable attributes in Machine Learning models?

Tags: machine-learning

What machine learning techniques can be used to make a model if some attributes change over time? For example predicting prices of a hotel depends on the number of tourists in the city which is time dependent i.e. it changes from time to time.

Also, if we have a good trained model on some static data, then what are the ways to update the model if some data is changed except retraining the model on complete data again?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first question, I would just add a feature indicating time. For instance, hotel X will appear in few data records, each one differs in the value of it's "Month" feature (the data-point of August might have an higher price from the one of December). This way the model will take into consideration the time of the year.

Regarding the second question, unless you're using reinforcement learning / online learning, which is used to train models from an oncoming sequences of samples, I don't see a way to change the data without having the train to model again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Can you please provide me some more insight on reinforcement/online learning?